# How to read received SMS message from Twilio Programmable SMS API

Tags: sms, twilio

I like to ask How to read all received SMS message from Twilio Programmable SMS API (based on certain date).

I managed to figure out how to read all SMS message sent but can't find much resources around how to fetch all received SMS message, not sent.

Below is how you can read sent SMS message, not received message (sent After certain date)
Appreciate in advance.

```
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var messages = MessageResource.Read(
            dateSentAfter: new DateTime(2018, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0)
            );
        foreach (var record in messages)
        {
            Response.Write(record.DateCreated + ", From: " + record.From + ", To:" + record.To + "</br>" + " Body: " +   record.Body + "</br></br>");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript use months 0 - 11 rather then 1 - 12.

So take this, using the date your currently have as the filter.

```
let a = new DateTime(2018, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0)
console.log(a)
```

Result: **2019-01-06T00:00:00.000Z**

What you want is new DateTime(2018, 11, 6, 0, 0, 0)

Result: **2018-12-06T00:00:00.000Z**

See if that fixes the issue.

The dateSent field is in both sent and received messages. You can set the To to your Twilio phone number to further reduce the dataset down to received SMS messages for that date.